# io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver cannot be cast to io.appium.java_client.clipboard.HasClipboard

Tags: java, automation, appium

I am trying to getdata from the clipboard.
I have used the below code, but i am getting an error

```
classcastexception:io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver cannot be cast
to io.appium.java_client.clipboard.HasClipboard
```

Could someone please help

```
    driver.findElement((By.xpath("/html/body/ion-app/ion-alert/div/div[3]/button/span"))).click();
                        //Thread.sleep(10000);
  ((HasClipboard) driver).getClipboard(ClipboardContentType.PLAINTEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the original commit that added clipboard support](https://github.com/appium/java-client/commit/2f60e64d74b7de0ea81b517f63fb984b694cbeeb#diff-da1a8b46707a71e02e7d8fc68b052b34), only `AndroidDriver` and `IOSDriver` have been given the power to do clipboard manipulation.

Therefore, you must use either of those, not the generic `AppiumDriver`.